# Dynamically adding table rows in js, sum up an input values

Tags: javascript

Hey guys I have a question and I'm looking for help to change this code a lil bit cause I'm struggling to do this for the last hour and I can't seem to figure it out how to change it.

This script works exactly how I want it to be. I can add an input field, I can delete input field and what's the most important it sum up all values.

https://jsfiddle.net/btxjkgr4/3/

What I need is to change this script that It can instead of creating div's, create next table rows with 3 columns to fit this table and sum up all values from 3rd column in each row

```
<table class="table" id="tab_klasa1">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-031ec" colspan="3">Class</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031ec">Name</td>
    <td class="tg-031ec">Profile</td>
    <td class="tg-031ec">No. Users</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-031e">A</td>
    <td class="tg-031e"><input class="input_t4" type="text" name="fname"></td>
    <td class="tg-031e"><input class="input_t4" type="text" name="fname"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4lcr" colspan="2">Total:</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"><input class="input_t4" type="text" name="fname"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I applied table in this jsfiddle. I'd really appreciate for help.